# Django batching/bulk update_or_create?

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I have data in the database which needs updating periodically. The source of the data returns everything that's available at that point in time, so will include new data that is not already in the database.

As I loop through the source data I don't want to be making 1000s of individual writes if possible.

Is there anything such as `update_or_create` but works in batches?

One thought was using `update_or_create` in combination with manual transactions, but I'm not sure if that just queues up the individual writes or if it would combine it all into one SQL insert?

Or similarly could using `@commit_on_success()` on a function with `update_or_create` inside a the loop work?

I am not doing anything with the data other than translating it and saving it to a model. Nothing is dependent on that model existing during the loop.

Comment: I think that there is no one single query for update or create in most sql servers. There is one in [postgres 9.5](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29) but django has no support for it.

Transactions will not result in "single" query. it will just ensure that all queries will fail if one fails. In fact it will slowdown all queries.

Comment: Upd. I was wrong about transactions. Using single transaction for all operations WILL speedup your writes. This is at least true for postgres and sqlite: https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities/pull/85#issuecomment-125177370

Answer (score 44):

As of Django 4.1, the **[`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)** method supports *upserts* via **`update_conflicts`**, which is the single query, batch equivalent of **`update_or_create`**:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    b = models.IntegerField()

objects = [Foo(1, 1), Foo(1, 2)]

Foo.objects.bulk_create(
    objects, 
    update_conflicts=True,
    unique_fields=['a'],
    update_fields=['b'],
)
```

Answer (score 12):

Since Django added support for bulk_update, this is now somewhat possible, though you need to do 3 database calls (a get, a bulk create, and a bulk update) per batch.  It's a bit challenging to make a good interface to a general purpose function here, as you want the function to support both efficient querying as well as the updates.  Here is a method I implemented that is designed for bulk update_or_create where you have a number of common identifying keys (which could be empty) and one identifying key that varies among the batch.

This is implemented as a method on a base model, but can be used independently of that.  This also assumes that the base model has an `auto_now` timestamp on the model named `updated_on`; if this is not the case, the lines of the code that assume this have been commented for easy modification.

In order to use this in batches, chunk your updates into batches before calling it.  This is also a way to get around data that can have one of a small number of values for a secondary identifier without having to change the interface.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    @classmethod
    def bulk_update_or_create(cls, common_keys, unique_key_name, unique_key_to_defaults):
        """
        common_keys: {field_name: field_value}
        unique_key_name: field_name
        unique_key_to_defaults: {field_value: {field_name: field_value}}
        
        ex. Event.bulk_update_or_create(
            {"organization": organization}, "external_id", {1234: {"started": True}}
        )
        """
        with transaction.atomic():
            filter_kwargs = dict(common_keys)
            filter_kwargs[f"{unique_key_name}__in"] = unique_key_to_defaults.keys()
            existing_objs = {
                getattr(obj, unique_key_name): obj
                for obj in cls.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs).select_for_update()
            }
            
            create_data = {
                k: v for k, v in unique_key_to_defaults.items() if k not in existing_objs
            }
            for unique_key_value, obj in create_data.items():
                obj[unique_key_name] = unique_key_value
                obj.update(common_keys)
            creates = [cls(**obj_data) for obj_data in create_data.values()]
            if creates:
                cls.objects.bulk_create(creates)

            # This set should contain the name of the `auto_now` field of the model
            update_fields = {"updated_on"}
            updates = []
            for key, obj in existing_objs.items():
                obj.update(unique_key_to_defaults[key], save=False)
                update_fields.update(unique_key_to_defaults[key].keys())
                updates.append(obj)
            if existing_objs:
                cls.objects.bulk_update(updates, update_fields)
        return len(creates), len(updates)

    def update(self, update_dict=None, save=True, **kwargs):
        """ Helper method to update objects """
        if not update_dict:
            update_dict = kwargs
        # This set should contain the name of the `auto_now` field of the model
        update_fields = {"updated_on"}
        for k, v in update_dict.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
            update_fields.add(k)
        if save:
            self.save(update_fields=update_fields)
```

Example usage:

```
class Event(BaseModel):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    external_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    started = models.BooleanField()


organization = Organization.objects.get(...)
updates_by_external_id = {
    1234: {"started": True},
    2345: {"started": True},
    3456: {"started": False},
}
Event.bulk_update_or_create(
    {"organization": organization}, "external_id", updates_by_external_id
)
```

### Possible Race Conditions

The code above leverages a transaction and select-for-update to prevent race conditions on updates.  There is, however, a possible race condition on inserts if two threads or processes are trying to create objects with the same identifiers.

The easy mitigation is to ensure that the combination of your common_keys and your unique_key is a database-enforced uniqueness constraint (which is the intended use of this function).  This can be achieved with either the unique_key referencing a field with `unique=True`, or with the unique_key combined with a subset of the common_keys enforced as unique together by a [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint)).  With database-enforced uniqueness protection, if multiple threads are trying to perform conflicting creates, all but one will fail with an `IntegrityError`.  Due to the enclosing transaction, threads that fail will perform no changes and can be safely retried or ignored (a conflicting create that failed could just be treated as a create that happened first and then was immediately overwritten).

If leveraging uniqueness constraints is not possible, then you will either need to implement your own concurrency control or [lock the entire table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19686204/2800876).

Comment: Very nice! I did something similar but not designed as nicely as yours. I did run into a problem with race conditions though for the creation. If you have two instances of this application deployed and each gets a call with the same data, The first may INSERT  after the second does its SELECT, leading to an integrity error on any unique fields. I ended up locking the table to prevent that.

Comment: @c6754 That race condition is why this implementation is inside a transaction and uses select_for_update on all data

Comment: @Zags Maybe my comment is postgres specific. But in postgres select_for_update will only lock those rows that already exist, not the whole table. So you are not prevented from creating the same row twice like I described above.

Comment: @c6754 Maybe this is a difference of use-case.  When I've used this, it's usually selecting on database-unique fields (such as the PK of the table), so one of those two updates would fail by violating a uniqueness constraint.  Is that not the case for you?

Comment: @Zags It's not the updates that are the problem, it's the inserts. When there are two application instances running and if both get the same request at almost the same time there is a chance that fastest one INSERTs a new row after the slow one has performed the SELECT for existing_objs, but before the slower INSERT. So then the slower bulk create raises an IntegrityError because of a duplicate PK. Which isn't handled here and so would presumably cause a 500 error. I guess it could also be prevented by using `ignore_conflicts`, but then you might miss an update.

Answer (score 3):

Batching your updates is going to be an upsert command and like @imposeren said, Postgres 9.5 gives you that ability. I think Mysql 5.7 does as well (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) depending on your exact needs. That said it's probably easiest to just use a db cursor. Nothing wrong with that, it's there for when the ORM just isn't enough.

Something along these lines should work. It's psuedo-ish code, so don't just cut-n-paste this but the concept is there for ya.

```py
class GroupByChunk(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.count = 0
        self.size = size
        self.toggle = False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.count >= self.size:  # Allows for size 0
            self.toggle = not self.toggle
            self.count = 0
        self.count += 1
        return self.toggle

def batch_update(db_results, upsert_sql):
    with transaction.atomic():
        cursor = connection.cursor()   
        for chunk in itertools.groupby(db_results, GroupByChunk(size=1000)):
            cursor.execute_many(upsert_sql, chunk)
```

Assumptions here are:

- `db_results` is some kind of results iterator, either in a list or dictionary
- A result from `db_results` can be fed directly into a raw sql exec statement
- If any of the batch updates fail, you'll be rolling back ALL of them. If you want to move that to for each chunk, just push the `with` block down a bit

Answer (score 2):

There is [django-bulk-update-or-create](https://pypi.org/project/django-bulk-update-or-create/) library for Django that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the @Zags answer and I think it's the best solution. But I'd want to advice about a little issue in his code.

```
        update_fields = {"updated_on"}
        updates = []
        for key, obj in existing_objs.items():
            obj.update(unique_key_to_defaults[key], save=False)
            update_fields.update(unique_key_to_defaults[key].keys())
            updates.append(obj)
        if existing_objs:
            cls.objects.bulk_update(updates, update_fields)
```

If you are using auto_now=True fields they are not going to be updated if you use .update() or bulk_update() this is because the fields "auto_now" triggers with a .save() as you can read in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now).

In case you have an auto_now field F.e: updated_on, it will be better to add it explicitly in the unique_key_to_defaults dict.

```
"unique_value" : {
        "field1.." : value...,
        "updated_on" : timezone.now()
    }...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older version of Django below version 4 you can apply my solution but for latest version you can do It as @LordElrond suggested it.

**model:**

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    RATINGS = (
        (1, '1 star'),
        (2, '2 stars'),
        (3, '3 stars'),
        (4, '4 stars'),
        (5, '5 stars'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=RATINGS)
```

**utils:**

```
 class ModelUtils():
    def __init__(self, model, datasets, unique_column):
       self.model = model
       self.datasets = datasets
       self.unique_column = unique_column

    def update(self, dataset_ids):
       fields = list(self.datasets[0].keys())
       fields = [field for field in fields if field != 'id']
       existing_datasets = self.model.objects.filter(
           **{self.unique_column + '__in': dataset_ids}
       ).values(**fields)
       if existing_datasets:           
          self.model.objects.bulk_update(
             [self.model(**d) for d in existing_datasets], fields
          )
       existing_dataset_ids = [d[unique_column] for d in existing_datasets]
       return existing_dataset_ids


    def create(self, dataset_ids, existing_dataset_ids):
        new_dataset_ids = set(dataset_ids) - set(existing_dataset_ids)
        new_datasets = [d for d in self.datasets if d[self.unique_column] 
                        not in existing_dataset_ids]
        self.model.objects.bulk_create(
            [self.model(**d) for d in new_datasets]
        )


    def update_or_create(self):        
        dataset_ids = [d[self.unique_column] for d in self.datasets]
        existing_dataset_ids = self.update(dataset_ids)
        new_dataset_ids = self.create(dataset_ids, existing_dataset_ids)
```

You can run it like this:

```
datasets = [
    {'name': 'apple', 'rating': 1}, 
    {'name': 'orange', 'rating': 2},
    {'name': 'grapes', 'rating': 4},
    {'name': 'mango', 'rating': 3}
]

model_utils = ModelUtils(Product, datasets, 'name')
model_utils.update_or_create(Product, datasets, 'name')
```

In total 3 queries will be happening always instead of n number of queries (if you are updating and creating in a loop for example using [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)).