# How to catch IntegrityError with ManyToMany add() with wrong ids?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have two models (just for example):

```
class One(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField()
    twos = models.ManyToManyField(Two)

class Two(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField()
```

When I try to add a list of `ids` of model `Two` to model `One` with `one.twos.add(*[id1, id2])` it works until I pass a wrong `id`, when this fails with

```
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "one_twos" violates foreign key constraint "one_two_id_572a5216_fk_twos"
DETAIL:  Key (two_id)=(e2871924-5bb4-492e-b7c3-4c5ca3cc7f5e) is not present in table "twos_two".

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "one_twos" violates foreign key constraint "one_two_id_572a5216_fk_twos"
DETAIL:  Key (two_id)=(e2871924-5bb4-492e-b7c3-4c5ca3cc7f5e) is not present in table "twos_two".
```

This does not seem to be the race condition (mentioned here [Django: IntegrityError during Many To Many add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654072/django-integrityerror-during-many-to-many-add)).

I need to tell the front-end that such-and-such `id` is not valid, but I can't catch these two `IntergityErrors` to re-raise my custom exception with a message and `id`.

Would highly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best somution, but one thing you can try is to:
Create a set of all ids in Two:

```
two_ids_set = set(Two.objects.all().values_list("id", flat=True))
```

then you can check for intersection or difference between sets.
For example:

V Difference will return all invalid ids (id that are not present in table Two)

```
set([id1, id2]).difference(two_ids_set)
```

V Intersection will return all valid ids (ids that are present in table Two)

```
set([id1, id2]).intersection(two_ids_set)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! To be honest, the only solution I could think of was also set().difference. Glad that it's confirmed by your suggestion as well. I'll wait to see if there are any "built-in" solutions or explanations, and if there are none, I'll accept your answer.