# Django: Maintaining a counter in a field (race condition)

Tags: django, transactions, race-condition

I have a model similar to this example

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(...)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        if self.pk is None:            
            current_max = (
                Foo.objects
                .filter(a=self.a)
                .order_by('-number')
                .first()
            )
            current_max = 0 if current_max is None else current_max.number
            self.number = current_max + 1
        return super().save(commit)
```

The idea is that for each `a`, there will be a series of `Foo`s numbered from 1 and then onwards.

The issue is that, even though we have `@transaction.atomic`, there is a race condition, because the transaction isolation level that Django expects will allow the transactions to run simultaneously, i.e.

```
A -> Get max -> 42
B -> Get max -> 42
A -> Set max + 1
A -> save
B -> Set max + 1
B -> save
Both will be 43
```

So how would I go about solving that? Is there a way to atomically setting the counter so I don't get the race condition between retrieving the current max and inserting the new value?

This question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598932/atomic-increment-of-a-counter-in-django), but different enough that that question did not provide an answer to my specific example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update).  As described in the docs:

> Returns a queryset that will lock rows until the end of the transaction, generating a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SQL statement on supported databases.

Alternatively, there's two approaches defined by Haki Benata at https://web.archive.org/web/20170707121253/https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2 which may be of interesting reading

Finally, if you need to lock the entire table, there's a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41831049/214892) described that would allow you to do that.  Effectively, you create a locking context manager that acquires a full table lock and releases it on exit

Comment: This locks a *row*. But here we need to lock the table, since at this moment, there is no row that maps to the instance, and the aggregate spans over the table.

Comment: You final idea, referencing the `LockedAtomicTransaction` from another answer is an appropriate solution for me, it seems. Thank you