# How to make your custom django migrations reversible?

Tags: django, migration, database-migration, django-migrations

My original problem was, given a db table with 60M rows I need to convert a field type from boolean to integer field. I thought of creating a custom django migration for this (please do let me know if you have a better approach than this) which looks like this-

```
def make_changes(apps, schema_editor):
    vcs_model = apps.get_model('iot_app', 'AbstractVCSCompartmentData')
    vcs_model.objects.select_related('vcsdata').all().update(charging_status_v2=F('charging_status'))
    vcs_model.objects.select_related('vcsdata').all().update(charging_status_backup=F('charging_status'))  # backup




class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('iot_app', '0030_auto_20220225_1027.py'),
    ]

    operations = [

        migrations.AddField(  # backup field
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            name='charging_status_backup',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),


        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            name='charging_status_v2',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),

        migrations.RunPython(make_changes),

        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            name='charging_status',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            old_name='charging_status_v2',
            new_name='charging_status',
        ),
    ]
```

I want to unroll all the changes i.e., making my custom migration reversible.
I have gone through [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) doc. But I am confused as in how can i perform addition of a new field in my `reverse_code()` function.

The idea of creating a backup field is to reinstate the db to its previous state.

Is this is the correct approach, given I have 60M rows in that table? wouldn't it lock the table for the time being? I want to do this as efficient as possible

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting when you reverse this migration? Converting a boolean to an integer is trivial, but the other way around not so much. What should happen with values greater than 1?

Comment: ```field1``` is the original field and the idea is -  
Step 1: Create two new fields, ```field_v2``` and ```field_backup``` which would be an integer field and a boolean field
Step 2: fill the values of ```field1``` into ```field_v2``` and ```field_backup```
Step 3: Now delete the ```field1```
Step 4: rename the ```field_v2``` to ```field```

So now If I need to revert this migrations, i got to 
Delete the ```field_v2```
rename ```field_backup``` to ```field```

Comment: in this case, you just copy the data from `field_backup` to `field`. Because `field` is already there.

You just need to provide a backwards function to your `RunPython` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i edited my answer after your comments - at the moment when `RunPython` is executed in reversion step, `charging_status` has been renamed to `charging_status_v2` and the old `charging_status` field is present. So you can copy directly from backup to `charging_status`

```
def make_changes(apps, schema_editor):
    vcs_model = apps.get_model('iot_app', 'AbstractVCSCompartmentData')
    vcs_model.objects.select_related('vcsdata').all().update(charging_status_v2=F('charging_status'))
    vcs_model.objects.select_related('vcsdata').all().update(charging_status_backup=F('charging_status'))  # backup


def backwards(apps, schema_editor):
    vcs_model = apps.get_model('iot_app', 'AbstractVCSCompartmentData')
    vcs_model.objects.select_related('vcsdata').all().update(charging_status=F('charging_status_backup'))



class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('iot_app', '0030_auto_20220225_1027.py'),
    ]

    operations = [

        migrations.AddField(  # backup field
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            name='charging_status_backup',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),


        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            name='charging_status_v2',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),

        migrations.RunPython(make_changes, backwards),

        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            name='charging_status',
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='AbstractVCSCompartmentData',
            old_name='charging_status_v2',
            new_name='charging_status',
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: I am concerned about how this will affect the db, will this create any downtime. If I do this will the table be locked during these operation? Could you please explain me a little bit on the db level, how this will play out?

Comment: afaik - it will not create any downtime - we run huge migrations - but always have maintenance mode enabled (would always be best i think). I don't have experience with migrating databases during heavy workloads. What you could do is a table lock in every function - something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686204/django-orm-and-locking-table

Comment: ```vcs_model.objects.select_related('vcsdata').all().update(charging_status_v2=F('charging_status'))```I want to do this without locking the table and the update here will lock the table i think.

Comment: Then you need to iterate over the objects and set it directly.